# How do I stop smelling like a wet dog?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Whenever I meet a guard, they nonchalantly tell me I smell of wet dog. That was par for the course when I was a lycanthrope, but I got better. According to [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Guard#Reactions_to_Player.27s_Condition), *guards may refer to you as a werewolf even if you have been cured of lycanthropy*. How do I get guards to stop telling me I smell like a wet dog?

Comment: Are you looking for a mod or something? Otherwise the question appears to answer itself.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm not sure how the question "how do I get guards to stop telling me I smell like a wet dog?" answers itself. I am fine with mods, console commands and other tricks.

Comment: Closing as mod recommendation (you admit there's no way to fix this without a mod), which is off topic

Comment: @badp except that's totally not what I said. There's a fair chance a console command can fix this bug.

Comment: Save game editing should work too, not just mods (remove "The Silver Hand" quest from the character, set the global PlayerIsWerewolf to 0).

Comment: Voting to reopen as I believe that the close reason (that this is a mod recommendation question) does not apply to this question. It just so happens that [the solution](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/87080/4797) I know for this issue, is to use a mod. @badp Are questions asking for mod recommendations not allowed? Can anyone point me to the related meta post(s)? I'm genuinely curious as [a lot of my rep are from recommending mods on Skyrim-tagged questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bskyrim%5D%20user:4797%20is%3aanswer).

Comment: I originally read this as "the game has a bug that makes X impossible. How do I do X?", which is just unclear/vague/somewhat confusing/contradictory. My comment was because it wasn't obvious what the question was asking for. If it were edited to read more like "there's this bug, ok? Is there a fix or workaround?" then it would get my (up/reopen) vote. I mean, now we know what you *mean*, but it's NARQ if it doesn't say what you mean, right?

Comment: @galacticninja: Mod recommendation questions are not specifically off-topic, but they can be off-topic if they are not being used to solve an actual problem, as is outlined in [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2334/are-questions-asking-for-non-game-recommendations-off-topic). Whether or not this would apply to this question is irrelevant though because he's not asking for mods. Just because the accepted answer uses a mod as a solution doesn't mean that this question is a mod recommendation in any shape or form.

Comment: @galacticninja They're not allowed as an extension of game recommendation questions not being allowed.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don't really know how to rewrite the question without making it worse. As it is I provide the most detail about my problem and, in the last sentence, present my question question. Would it be better as "Guards tell me I smell like a wet dog. How do I make them stop"?

Comment: @kotekzot Just incorporating the substance of the comment that cleared it up would make a difference. (Right now it's possible to misread it as asking for gameplay method of fixing the guard's perception of the character. Asking explicitly for a workaround or fix for the bug wouldn't require potential answerers to guess what you mean.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I've edited the last sentence, is this what you meant?

Comment: Works for me, and it's been reopened already anyway.

Comment: @badp Not all mod recommendation questions suffer the same problem as game recommendation questions, which were deemed off-topic for very specific reasons. See [GraceNotes answer here.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2334/are-questions-asking-for-non-game-recommendations-off-topic) The key point to take away is that if the question can be re-written as an actual problem then it doesn't suffer from the same issues as game recommendation does, and is therefore not off-topic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Install the **[Shut The F--- Up](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/10023)** mod. According to its mod page, it removes the "*Is that... fur? Coming out of your ears?*" comment from guards. Not sure if it also removes the other werewolf-related comments, though.

[Mod description, from its webpage](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/10023):

> This mod simply gets rid of all the annoying NPC dialogue that you've been tired of hearing over and over again. It mostly affects NPCs in Whiterun, but there are a few others for Markarth and Solitude. This mod includes two separate ESP files: one for guards (STFU - guards.esp) and one for everyone else (STFU.esp). You can choose to use both or just one. Let me know if there are NPCs in other cities that you want to STFU.
>
> Update v2
>
> This update removes a few more lines of dialogue. I've also separated
> the dialogue into two separate ESP files: one for guards (STFU -
> guards.esp) and one for everyone else (STFU.esp). You can choose to
> use both or just one.

Another option is to use the [**No NPC Greetings**](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/746) mod. This will affect all NPCs though, not just guards. Depending on which components of the mod you installed, this will either completely stop NPCs from auto-greeting you or reduce the distance required before an NPC automatically talks to you or greets you. That should shut those snotty guards up.

A mod that specifically aims to improve guard dialogue (as mention by kotekzot) is [**Guard Dialogue Overhaul** (PC)](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/23390) / [(Xbox One)](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4091492) / [(PS4)](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4098809):

Mod description:

> This Mod alters the Guards' Dialogue, changing it from something that breaks your immersion in the world of Skyrim to something that actually increases it. All in the original voices and Fully compliant with Skyrim Lore.
>
> GDO fixes All the Skyrim Guards dialogue bugs and does much, much more.
>
> GDO alters the effect that Skyrim Guard dialogue has on the mood of your game. Rather than annoying you, guards will enhance your experience of the game and increase your immersion in the world of Skyrim by properly recognising your actions and not making disrespectful comments to a character that they are supposed to respect.

<sup>Personally, I would have not cured myself of Lycanthropy and just eat the next guard that talks to me in a slight way.</sup>

Comment: No NPC greetings seems promising, but I sort of enjoy the random chatter as long as it isn't obviously out of place.

Comment: @kotekzot I believe *No NPC Greetings* only stops or reduces the trigger distance before an NPC automatically talks to or auto-greets the player character. This includes dialogues where guards mention that the player seems to be.. *wolfish*. Other chatter, like NPCs talking to each other should not be affected. You might want to try the  '*Slightly reduced distance*' or the '*Reduced distance*' versions of No NPC Greetings. I use the '*Slighly reduced distance*' version myself. NPCs still automatically talk to or greet me, but only if I am near those NPCs.

Comment: *Three* consecutive "minus" signs in a (mod) name? And I thought `C++` was too silly already ...

Comment: I settled on Guard Dialogue Overhaul, it removes the werewolf lines as well as sprucing up their dialogue in general. http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/23390

Comment: @kotekzot That seems to be a useful mod. Adding it to my mod list too.

Answer (score 7):

The condition for the guards' "werewolf" dialogue is that you have completed stage 30 of "The Silver Hand" quest, not whether you currently are a werewolf or not. You could try using the console commands `resetquest C03`, then `setstage C03 200` to mark the quest as completed without stage 30 being marked as completed, though this can have potential side-effects (if the quality of scripting for the werewolf dialogue is any indication of Bethesda's scripting ability).

The condition for these lines have been fixed by the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/23390) to include a check for player's werewolf status, however sometimes the game may not properly register the fact that you are cured of lycanthropy. To get the game up to speed, use `set PlayerIsWerewolf to 0`.

Another solution is to try the mods from galacticninja's answer or [Guard Dialogue Overhaul](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/23390), my personal favorite, it makes guards progressively more courteous to you depending on your accomplishments and enables some lines which previously were too restricted to be seen in normal gameplay, such as recognizing you as a thane. Some lines are even accompanied by the guard standing to attention or putting their right fist on their chest.

Comment: My personal annoyance is the "*...you're that new member of the Companions. So you what - fetch the mead?*" Which the guards say even if you have finished the companions quest line and are already the Harbinger of the Companions. Does *Guard Dialogue Overhaul* fix that?

Comment: I believe this is the direct link to the bug report of the guard werewolf dialogue bug at the USKP tracker: http://bugzilla.darkcreations.org/show_bug.cgi?id=307#c12

Comment: @galacticninja it does, at least after you've become a Skyrim celebrity. Thanks for the link, added.